# Jest+NextJs: You should only use "next/router" on the client side of your app

Tags: jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library

I'm mocking the `next/router` dependency in my Jest+React-testing-libray tests as I always have:

```
import * as nextRouter from 'next/router';

export const routerData = {
  pathname: '/users/create',
  route: '/users/create',
  query: { },
  asPath: '/users/create',
  isFallback: false,
  basePath: '',
  isReady: true,
  isPreview: false,
  isLocaleDomain: false,
  events: {},
};

// mock router
jest.mock('next/router');
nextRouter.useRouter.mockImplementation(() => (routerData));

describe('a component that requires next/router, () => ... );
```

This had been working correctly but after updating to NextJs `12.2.0` I get this warning:

> No router instance found.
> You should only use "next/router" on the client side of your app.

This warning makes all my tests with the mocked router to fail.

Ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it appears that this is not related to `12.2.0`. Somehow my last version of Next - `12.0.0` - wasn't thrownig this error but other older versions did.

Thanks to **bistacos** for the response [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13891#discussioncomment-382441).

```
const useRouter = jest.spyOn(require('next/router'), 'useRouter');
useRouter.mockImplementation(() => ({
  pathname: '/',
  ...moreRouterData
}));
```